# How can I extract and pair the values of an array based object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, playwright

I'm trying to create a String based upon an object consisting of several key-value pairs.

Example:

```
  [{ name: 'cookie1', value: 'false' },
  { name: 'cookie2', value: '123' },
  { name: 'cookie3',value: 'abc'}]
```

What I'm trying to achieve (string):

```
cookie1: false, cookie2: 123, cookie3: abc
```

I've tried to extract just the val using map like this (played around moving around values):

```
var output = cookies.map(d => {
  return {
    "name": d.name,
    "value": d.value, 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to `map` the array of objects into `name: value` strings and then `join` them with `,` :

```js
const data =   [{ name: 'cookie1', value: 'false' },
  { name: 'cookie2', value: '123' },
  { name: 'cookie3',value: 'abc'}]
  
const result = data.map(({ name, value }) => `${name}: ${value}`).join(', ')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: This is beautiful and simple. Makes total sense. Thanks